# How did I get 42 votes on posts?

Tags: support, voting

Looking at [my user profile](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/95/kiamlaluno), I see I have voted posts 42 times, and I have reached the limit for today.

How can that be possible, if the limit is 40 per day?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Dunno if it's relevant, but it says [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) regarding recent changes, *2012-04-20: On Stack Overflow, 50 votes available daily for suggested edits, not 40*

Comment: Strange, the best I can think of is that in beta version there is no that limit or that there is a GMT problem today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is for suggested edits; it's the number of times you can accept/reject a suggested edit per day. Then, Stack Overflow is a different beast: The limits there are generally higher than in other sites. That is what happens for the number of votes to accept/reject a suggested edit, for example; while in other site that is two, on Stack Overflow is three (e.g. until three users don't vote to accept the suggested edit, the suggested edit is not accepted).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Votes on deleted posts do not count towards your daily total.

*Ref. [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124172/98786)*